# How fast can you run, drive, and swim in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4

In meters per second (the game measures distance in meters right), how fast can you run, drive, and swim? Obviously there are different kinds of vehicles that can go at different max speeds, so just name the ones that you know the speed of.

Comment: Is that the Battlefield Triathalon?

Comment: LOL, no. :P I was going to use the info to figure out the best way to get to a location under certain circumstances i.e. you have to swim at some point but there is some ground that you can run faster on, but it is a longer path.

Comment: Best way to get to a location? Spawn there! Or use a jet, it travels at 400+ kmh :)

Comment: @Novarg no pls do not be that kind of person who grabs one jet and then jump when he arrives the location, making the team lose the jet.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://symthic.com/bf4-vehicle-stats?MBT) you can check the speed for every vehicle in the game. They write it's "outdated" but surely they'll update it and even if not, it's a good clue to compare vehiclespeed.

Units unknown, kmh or mph I guess.

```
MBT -> 56
IFV -> 65
MAA -> 56
ART -> unknown (slow)
```

I did not find a source, but with 3000 IFV kills I got a little experience and I'm pretty sure they differe. LAV is accelating faster than BMP, if the topspeed differs is unsure.

Check walking speed [here](http://forum.symthic.com/battlefield-4-technical-discussion/5437-moving-speeds-in-bf4/) (in progress).
Running is (any weapon) 6.66 m/s
Walking (pistol) 3.33 m/s

This post is older than fall-update which brought the BF3 movement in BF4. So the stats might be outdated but still give a clue.